# Postgres: missing FROM-clause entry for nested queries with with

Tags: postgresql

i know i could solve this with transactions and several queries, but for the sake of the argument, and to learn something new to me, i tried to compress everything into one request,

i have a table where all the tables are listed in deftables, a table tableheader where i can store titles for groups of records, acl where i store some access levels, user2acl that makes the binding between the user, a table, eventually a set of records in that table (as defined in tableheaders) and lastly a table with the userdata (personnes)  and another for eventual extra user pertinent data (pattributs).

the code comes from some php script using PDO and statements, for the example i extracted the bindings and inserted them directly into the request to be able to test it with psql....

```
WITH acl_asker_max AS
(   
  SELECT max(aclnames_asker.value) AS max_value FROM personnes AS asker_user
  JOIN deftables AS acl_names ON acl_names.name = 'newagenda'
  JOIN tableheader AS acl_index ON acl_index.name = 'sometype'
  JOIN user2acl AS acl_asker ON asker_user.id = acl_asker.userid
  JOIN acl AS aclnames_asker ON acl_asker.aclid = aclnames_asker.id
        WHERE asker_user.id = 5 AND acl_asker.tableid = acl_index.id
        AND acl_index.id is not null ), 
  check_acl AS (
 SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
     ( SELECT 1 FROM acl_asker_max, acl
   WHERE acl.name = 'caninsert'
      AND acl.value <= (SELECT max_value FROM acl_asker_max) )
     THEN true
           ELSE false END ),
   new_user AS (
 INSERT INTO personnes (login, passwd)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'titi' as login, 'something' as passwd FROM personnes
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM personnes WHERE login = 'titi')
    AND (SELECT true FROM check_acl)
 ON CONFLICT (login) 
               DO UPDATE SET passwd = excluded.passwd
 RETURNING id)      
 INSERT INTO pattributs (persid, name, value)
       SELECT new_user.id, name, value FROM (VALUES ('referentid', '3'),
         ('name', 'PasseP'),
   ('prenom', 'Titi')) AS data(name, value)
 JOIN new_user ON true
 ON CONFLICT (persid, name) WHERE persid = new_user.id
   DO UPDATE SET value = excluded.value;
```

which comes back with a

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_user"
```

LINE 30:      ON CONFLICT (persid, name) WHERE persid = new_user.id

in the stored subrequests i have defined new_user on line 17, with a returning clause that returns id, so in my understanding the from target new_user should exist and contain a column id?
or is the JOIN new_user ON true on line 29 the real problem? was unsure on that one, since i wanted to check if there were values in new_user....

Answer (score 0):

funny enough chatgpt was able to produce me a corrected version of my query:

```
 WITH acl_asker_max AS (
  SELECT max(aclnames_asker.value) AS max_value 
  FROM personnes AS asker_user
  JOIN deftables AS acl_names ON acl_names.name = 'newagenda'
  JOIN tableheader AS acl_index ON acl_index.name = 'sometype'
  JOIN user2acl AS acl_asker ON asker_user.id = acl_asker.userid
  JOIN acl AS aclnames_asker ON acl_asker.aclid = aclnames_asker.id
   WHERE asker_user.id = 5 AND acl_asker.tableid = acl_index.id AND    acl_index.id is not null
 ), 
check_acl AS (
 SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM acl_asker_max, acl
 WHERE acl.name = 'caninsert'
  AND acl.value <= (SELECT max_value FROM acl_asker_max)
 ) THEN true ELSE false END
),
new_user AS (
 INSERT INTO personnes (login, passwd)
  SELECT DISTINCT 'titi' as login, 'something' as passwd 
  FROM personnes
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM personnes WHERE login = 'titi')
  AND (SELECT true FROM check_acl)
   ON CONFLICT (login) DO UPDATE SET passwd = excluded.passwd
  RETURNING id
 )      
 INSERT INTO pattributs (persid, name, value)
  SELECT ins_user.id, name, value 
    FROM (VALUES ('referentid', '3'), ('name', 'PasseP'), ('prenom', 'Titi')) AS data(name, value)
   JOIN new_user as ins_user ON ins_user.id is not null
   ON CONFLICT (persid, name) DO UPDATE SET value = excluded.value 
     WHERE pattributs.persid = excluded.persid AND pattributs.name = excluded.name;
```

the last where clause, was misplaced....